# MYSQL query with session variable

Tags: php, mysql

The following query returns records of all the clients,
 Session `$_SESSION['client_id']` value is `3`. 
The query works fine but it returns records of all the clients . I want to apply the session value on all `SELECT Clauses`.

```
SELECT mrk_lat,client_id,mrk_lng ,engine_status ,created_date,live_fuel,
     (SELECT count(driver_id) FROM we_drivers) as total_drivers,
     (SELECT count(veh_id) FROM we_vehicles) as total_veh,
     (SELECT count(veh_status) FROM we_vehicles WHERE veh_status=1) as run_veh,
     (SELECT count(veh_status) FROM we_vehicles WHERE veh_status=0) as stop_veh,
     (SELECT client_id FROM we_clients WHERE client_id =" .  $_SESSION['client_id'] . ") 
            FROM `we_vehicles_coordinates`
```

Comment: If it's PHP code and is wrapped by `"`, it's okay. I mean `$sql = "..." . $_SESSION[''] . ") ...";`

Comment: Yes you need to JOIN the tables , how tables are related to `we_vehicles_coordinates` provide the schema.

Comment: @Panther Yeah its PHP code.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty , what about `INNER JOIN` with `we_clients table` and with session variable  for each `SELECT` ?

Comment: I am not aware of your table schema and can not predict the expected result,however you are doing count from different tables and this would give you all the count from those tables. So if you want to do count for a specific condition then yes it needs join. It would be good if you provide some sample data and expected result out of those, perhaps in http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Have a look  Please
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e42951

Comment: Looks like the fiddle went down, in the mean while please outline the expected result-set into the question.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Ok in a while.